# "ReferenceError: waitForElement is not defined" when testing react.js

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, react-testing-library

I am testing with Jest and react-testing-library a component that is calling an async function. When I run the test I get the error `ReferenceError: waitForElement is not defined`

Following [this instructions](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) I have tried:

1. without the `useBuiltins`option in `.babelrc`, including `@babel/polyfill` at the top of the `app.test.jsx` file, , and without `@babel/polyfill` in the entry array in `webpack.config.js`. I get the error `ReferenceError: waitForElement is not defined` from the test run but the application compiles succesfully
2. with `useBuiltIns: 'entry'`, including `@babel/polyfill` at the top of the `app.test.jsx` file, and without `@babel/polyfill` in the entry array in `webpack.config.js` . I get `Cannot find module 'core-js/modules/es6.array.every' from 'app.test.jsx'` and the application fails to compile.
3. with `useBuiltIns: 'entry'`, NOT including `@babel/polyfill` at the top of the `app.test.jsx` file, and WITH `@babel/polyfill` in the entry array in `webpack.config.js`. I get the error `ReferenceError: waitForElement is not defined` from the test run and the application fails to compile.

Here is the code from case 1:

**imports in app.test.jsx**

```
import '@babel/polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup } from 'react-testing-library';
import AppContainer from '../components/AppContainer';
```

**test in app.test.jsx**

```
test('State change', async () => {
  const { debug, getByLabelText, getByTestId, getByText } = render(<AppContainer />);

  fireEvent.change(getByLabelText('testfield'), { target: { value: 'Hello' } });
  fireEvent.click(getByTestId('button'));

  await waitForElement(() => getByText('return value'));
  debug();
});
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: './index.html',
    }),
  ],
};
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I am expecting the `waitForElement` function to be awaiting for the "return value" text to appear in a second textfield, and then the `debug()` function to print the page html code. Instead I get the above mentioned errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to import `waitForElement` from `react-testing-library`:

```
import { render, waitForElement } from 'react-testing-library'
```

There's no need to install `dom-testing-library` because RTL depends on it already.

Comment: ```import {waitForElement} from "@testing-library/dom";``` is giving the same error

Comment: This worked for me. Kind of annoying to have to import each metho individually instead of *. But is this because of bloat?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem. I was missing the `dom-testing-library` dependency.

Here is the working solution.

- Install dom-testing library: `npm install --save-dev dom-testing-library`.
- In `app.test.jsx`import `waitForElement` and `@babel/polyfill`:

```
import '@babel/polyfill';
import { waitForElement } from 'dom-testing-library';
```

- The rest of the code is as in case 1 above.